# jquery animation help, animation queuing and code cleaning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I really need some help with this. I'm 100% new to it. I need some general help on it. I hope you guys can help with cleaning up the code. Also, I would like to do this animation which I can't get to work now. The code is actually working great. It does what I would like to do. Scroll down, sticky the navigation when it reaches the top.

[Link to website](http://duiker-2.demon.nl/design/yvonne/test.html)

If you scroll down, the navigation bar appears, plus you'll see the ribbon on the left come down. **My problem:** scrolling back up makes it fade out just like I want to. But I can't get the ribbon to slide back up.
**Second problem:** Which comes to my general help/cleaning the code, the animation queues when scrolling up and down a few times.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {      var divh = document.getElementById('stnav').offsetHeight;
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stnav').offset().top;
        $('#logoheader').css('margin-top','-90px');
        $('#nav').hide();
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('#stnav').addClass("sticky");
                        $('#content').css('margin-top',divh);
                        $('#logoheader').animate({marginTop:"0"},800);
                        $('#nav').fadeIn(1500);
                } else  {
                        $('#stnav').removeClass("sticky");
                        $('#content').css('margin-top','0px');
                        $('#nav').fadeOut(1500);
                }
        })

    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version. Create the effect only the first time, not every time the user scrolls. Also, clear the current queue before creating a new animation.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
                    if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                            if(!$('#stnav').hasClass("sticky")){
                                $('#stnav').addClass("sticky");
                                $('#content').css('margin-top',divh);
                                $('#logoheader').stop(true, true).animate({marginTop:"0"},800);
                                $('#nav').stop(true, true).fadeIn(1500);
                            }
                    } else  {
                            if($('#stnav').hasClass("sticky")){
                                $('#stnav').removeClass("sticky");
                                $('#content').css('margin-top','0px');
                                $('#nav').stop(true, true).fadeOut(1500);
                            }
                    }
            })
```

Comment: Very nice! This works. I've added the code to slide the ribbon back up myself and it works flawlessly. Now I gotta z-index the header and I'm done. So let's see, you added more if statements? Awesome **Thanks you very much, I appreciate it!**

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

It fades in and out just fine for me in Firefox 10.

**Second:**

To prevent the animation from repeating it self use `stop()` or `stop(true, true)`.
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Does the ribbon not slide down for you?  (First time only - that's a side-effect of not sliding it back up).

Comment: Well, now that I look at it, it does just the first time you load the site, then it just fades in and out.

Comment: Yup that's my problem. I want it to slide back up first then fade out again. I tried chaining and adding another .animate with marginTop but it will not go back up... Very weird.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var divh = document.getElementById('stnav').offsetHeight;
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stnav').offset().top;
    $('#logoheader').css('margin-top','-90px');
    $('#nav').hide();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            $('#stnav').addClass("sticky");
            $('#content').css('margin-top',divh);
            $('#logoheader').stop().animate({marginTop:"0"},800);
            $('#nav').stop().fadeIn(1500);
        } else  {
            $('#stnav').removeClass("sticky");
            $('#content').css('margin-top','0px');
            $('#logoheader').stop().animate({marginTop:"-90px"},800);
            $('#nav').stop().fadeOut(1500);
        }
    })
});
```

Just replace your above code with that.

I've added the animate for the ribbon sliding up (you'd just missed it from the else block), and I've added stops before animations and fades, so they stop immediately, rather than complete before doing the next animate/fade.

Edit: Very nice site BTW!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be honest I already tried the .stop() thing. I copied your code but now there is another problem. The nav won't fade in at all. I removed the .stop() from the #nav and it will appear, but everything is super jerky and it will not fade in to 100%. Weird. And thanks! It's just a start. I'll do my best to make it a nice site!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought for this kind of problem is to stop the older animations (with .stop()) before starting the new ones.